# Windows security event ID 4769 Kerberos Error on single user Domain

Tags: kerberos, windows-event-log, network-security, window-server-2019

I have a test lab with a single Windows Server 2019 and a single Windows 10 Pro PC that connects to it, with a single user, me.  I test our own software on it and that's it.

As of the past few days I am seeing this error:

Log Name:      Security

Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing

Date:          11/19/2023 10:33:26 AM

Event ID:      4769

Task Category: Kerberos Service Ticket Operations

Level:         Information

Keywords:      Audit Failure

User:          N/A

Computer:      SERVERNAME.domain.local

Description:   A Kerberos service ticket was requested.

How do I even start to look at why this is given it's a static box -- no exotica being installed?

Comment: If none of the other usual fields are present in the event, you probably aren't going to get far. There is usually a result code and service/network details.

Comment: A downvote? I asked because that is all the data and the fact that it exists means something is triggering it.

What other useful fields do you mean?

Comment: home lab environment is offtopic usually

Comment: @djdomi

How is it off topic? It's a question about a server.  It's a dev lab, we also have production.  The site is serverfault, right?

Comment: @djdomi it is not offtopic, it is actually **encouraged** to set up test labs and do all the experiments before implementing something in the field.

Comment: sorry, but it sounds like the trillions of home lab question, but that is the point when [ask] is not read carefully ;)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by adding this to the registry. A hearty no thanks to the community members that piled on me for asking.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNS]
"DependOnService"=hex(7):54,00,63,00,70,00,69,00,70,00,00,00,41,00,66,00,64,00,
00,00,52,00,70,00,63,00,53,00,73,00,00,00,4e,00,54,00,44,00,53,00,00,00,4e,
00,65,00,74,00,4c,00,6f,00,67,00,6f,00,6e,00,00,00,00,00

Comment: while it might answer this question, i would suggest that you add references so we can proof it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).